# fix navigation at section

Tags: html, css

I want to fix my navigation. My problem is, i want a special position. I have a section this section is in the middle of the page with margin-left:auto & margin-right: auto. The navigation should be fixed at the left border of the section. Here is a picture [image: Picture]. Here is [myPage](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/Homepage) and here the Code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color: #4A3A47;
    height: 5000px;
}

section{
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
}


.divbox{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    border: 4px solid #D7E8D5;
    margin: 0 50px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    background-color: #D7E8D5;
}

.divbox:hover{
    border-bottom-right-radius: 75px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 75px; 
}



/* Bildern noch eine Klasse geben */

.divbox:hover img{
    border-bottom-right-radius: 75px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 75px;    
}

img{
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*---------------*/

nav{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #D7E8D5;
}

nav ul{
    border: border: 4px solid #D7E8D5;
}

nav ul a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #4A3A47;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Startseite</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <section>
            <article>
                <div class="divbox">
                    <img src="http://ipadminibackgrounds.com/assets/Battlefield-3-Game-iPad-mini-wallpaper-250x250.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
                </div>
                <div class="divbox">
                    <img src="http://static.planetminecraft.com/files/resource_media/screenshot/1341/11Minecraft-Creeper-Wallpaper-1080p-HD-250x250up_6509836_lrg.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
                </div>
                <div class="divbox">
                    <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Nv-tRjOe0Ww/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAMQ/81G-ZfxzYNc/photo.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like this? -----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dkx8wrL/1/embedded/result/). I'm guessing that you meant `position: fixed`.

Comment: Yep thats perfect! :) Now i have to understand it and then im happy. Maybe i ask later something :P and thanks for the nice comment!

Answer (score 1):

```
nav{
position: fixed;
background-color: #D7E8D5;
top:50%;
}
```

I think that should work

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) But no i searched not that... But thanks!

Comment: Oh I think I know what you mean, have you tried to to place the navigation inside your section and then adding margins to it?